# Pascal's law with bleeding port on the piston

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

If a bleeding port is drilled on the larger piston, does Pascal's law still hold as shown in the diagram? If yes, could you kindly provide some references for me to have a look at? Thanks in advance for your time!

[image: Pascal's law equations with and without bleeding]

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: My initial assumption is that for A3<<A2, the approximation should hold. But honestly, I am not sure where to start. I understand Pascal's law at a very basic level.

Comment: In my judgment, the pressure is going to be less than p  for a small region around the hole of area A3, as the flow converges toward the hole.  So F2 will be less than given by the final equation.

Comment: And do you think this can be characterized by a constant K where K<1? So basically, F2 = K*F1*(A2-A3)/A1? Could this be a linear relation for any fixed A1, A2 and A3?

Comment: That, I’m not so sure about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Overview

- Pascal's law does not hold if there is any fluid flow through the bleeding port.
- In the limits of large viscosity, $A_3\to0$ and low pressure difference between the vessel and surroundings then the approximation $\frac{F_2}{F_1}\approx\frac{A_2-A_3}{A_1}$ becomes increasingly accurate - with equality when there is no fluid flow.

### Explination

Pascal's law arises from the definition of pressure $p\equiv\frac{F}{A}$ and that the pressure is constant when there is no fluid flow (we can neglect the pressure due to gravity or other body forces if the pistons are at approximately the same level). As the pressure is constant we can just equate the pressures at each piston giving Pascal's law.

Now if we cut a hole of area $A_3$ in piston 2 then the pressure is only exerted over the area $A_2-A_3$ so then Pascal's law becomes $\frac{F_2}{F_1}\approx\frac{A_2-A_3}{A_1}$. However, this assumes we still have constant pressure, which would be the case if the fluid was not flowing through the hole.

Now we must consider what causes the fluid to flow through the hole. If there is a pressure difference across the hole then a force is applied to the particles in the fluid accelerating them until the viscous drag causes them to reach an equilibrium velocity. Thus, the particles in the immediate vicinity of the hole start to flow out of the hole. This in turn will reduce the pressure in that immediate volume which then accelerates particles further from the hole and the process repeats setting up a pressure gradient in the fluid. The pressure gradient is required as without it particles far from the hole would not "know" to start flowing and then we wouldn't get any flow through the hole.

This argument also applied in reverse with a larger pressure outside of the vessel and particles flowing in increasing the pressure in the immediate vicinity and so on. Therefore, unless there is no fluid flow then a pressure gradient will be set up in the fluid. The exact form of the pressure gradient is geometry dependent but a schematic diagram of the situation is given below:

[image]

The pressure is not constant on either piston, but even if we used the average pressure on each piston the relation would not hold as now the average pressure on piston 1 is less(greater) than on piston 2 when the pressure is greater(less) outside the vessel.

If we have a large but localised pressure gradient at the hole then the pressure across the piston 1 will be approximately constant and for the majority of piston 2 will be approximately constant and approximately equal to that across piston 1. Therefore, in the limit of an infinite pressure gradient (a step in pressure) at the hole Pascal's law will become an increasingly good approximation. The pressure gradient increases as the viscosity increases and the hole size decreases (from dimensional analysis of [Navier–Stokes equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations), but really all the important terms are in the [Stokes equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_flow#Stokes_equations)). Additionally, as the pressure difference decreases the accuracy of the approximation also increases as this localises the pressure gradient.

Now there may be specific geometries with a compensating temperature differential for which Pascal's law still holds but in general, it will not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That clarifies a lot of my confusion and gives me a better insight into the concept.